# ShellScript: How to create manually a parent process and their children process?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, process, command

I am reading this post:

- [Using job control in the shells](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=shells-using-job-control-in)

About `ppid` it indicates

```
PPID
A process that creates a new process is called a parent process; 
the new process is called a child process. 
The parent process ID (PPID) becomes associated with the new child process when it is created.
The PPID is not used for job control.
```

I understand the idea at a first glance. The theory part is practically clear ...

... but for *practical academic/experimental* purposes, and to learn very well the use of the `ps` and `pstree` commands. Through a shell script:

- How to create a parent process and N child process?

I mean a common/normal process, to then "convert" it to a parent process with a set of child process.

**Consideration:** do not close this question because is "wide" - I know there are a lot of commands, but if through an example is shared a *template* - to be applied in a shell script (`.sh`) - to understand and have clear the idea to know how create a parent and their children process for a set of commands - of course, if it is viable - would be great.

Comment: You cannot create a child on behalf of another process: only the parent process itself can create its own children. You could write a C program to do that, but the obvious method is to write a shell script which can create its own children, and then run that script (which thereby becomes the child of your login session and then makes those children of its own).

Comment: _"but the obvious method is to write a shell script which can create its own children, and then run that script (which thereby becomes the child of your login session and then makes those children of its own)"_ thanks - I hope it that be covered in the suggested question.

Comment: In general, processes are arranged in a *tree* structure. The suggested question specifically addresses what might be called a process *ladder* with depth,  and yours appears to want a *layer* -- one process with many immediate children. These are both subsets of the full tree case, but the same methods can be adapted to work for all. You might look at other posts by the poster of the referenced question to get a broader view.